# android interface object is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a childfragment which has -

```
private FavouriteMessageListener favouriteMessageListener;

msgListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FavouriteMessageWrapper favouriteMessage =  favourites.get(position);
                String favoriteMessage = favouriteMessage.getText();
                //Need to notify the interface about it
                favouriteMessageListener.favouriteMessageString(favoriteMessage);
                }
            });
```

My Interface

```
public interface FavouriteMessageListener {
     void favouriteMessageString(String favouriteMessage);
}
```

My MainFragment

```
@Override
    public void favouriteMessageString(String favouriteMessage) {

    }
```

Why my favouriteMessageListener is null? What is wrong with my implementation... I just need to get the value of string in MainFragment using this interface. How do I do?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12311939/5296734) out a possible help

Comment: @nick7291 This is a different example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your adapter

```
 // Define listener member variable
private static OnItemClickListener listener;
// Define the listener interface
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View itemView, int position, String favoriteMessaage);
}
// Define the method that allows the parent activity or fragment to define the listener
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

In your adapters ViewHolder:

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(v, k, favoriteMessage);
            }
        });
```

In your Fragment:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MenuListCustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position, String favoriteMessage) {


              // you can get your String here
              //you can check which view was clicked
               if(view.getId() == R.id.viewID){

                 //do your stuff here
               }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Actually I want to do it in fragment... I dont want to do in adapter

Comment: You want to get string from adapter to your fragment. This example indeed does that

Comment: No. I have a childfragment that has itemclick listener. From there I get a string as shown in my question. From there I need to notify my interface

Comment: Well my interface approach should work with your case too. Just use it in childfragment instead of adapter